# Expectation of a Normal distribution with dependent conditions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

$X$  and $Z$ are two independent Normal random variables and $k$ is a constant. I am interested in the following conditional expected value
$$E(X\mid X<k,X+Z>k).$$

Answer (score 2):

The general approach is:

$$  E[X| X<k, X+Z>k] = \frac{E[X1_{X<k, X+Z>k}]}{P(X<k, X+Z>k)} $$

$$ E[X1_{X<k, X+Z>k}] =  \iint_D x f_{X,Z} (x,z) dx dz$$

$$ P(X<k, X+Z>k) = \iint_D f_{X,Z} (x,z) dx dz $$

where $D =\{(x,z)\in \mathbf{R}^2 \mid   x<k, z >k-x \}  $.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming standard normal.  $E=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^k xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{(k-x)}^\infty e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz)dx$

Correction: should divide by $P(X\lt k,X+Z\gt k)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^k e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{(k-x)}^\infty e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}dz)dx$

Comment: Don't you have to divide out $P(X<k<X+Z)$?

Comment: @J.G.  Why?  The other answer is the same, but more elaborate in the presentation.

Comment: The integral you use simplifies a bit to $\frac{\frac{e^{-\frac{k^2}{4}} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)+1\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$.  But it does need to be divided by $P(X<k<X+Z)$ as stated by @J.G. because while your integral uses the correct limits of integration, you're also using the unconditional joint density of $X$ and $Z$ rather than the conditional density.  I haven't found a simplification for that divisor.  Probably numerical integration is necessary.

Comment: @JimB Can you explain how you simplified the integral? As for $P(<<+)$, would it be equal to $P(+Z>) - P(>)$?

Comment: @Iman I used *Mathematica* to simplify that integral.  Also, your conjecture about using $P(X+Z>k)-P(X<k)$ doesn't work because that results in a negative value for any $k>0$.

Comment: Corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks @herbsteinberg. My concern is that computing this expected value based on the formulation you provided is almost impractical, especially in settings this has to be calculated numerous times in a small amount of time. Is there any way this can be simplified (plus, what's proposed is for standard normal and no a generic normal)?

Comment: Computation is difficult.  For generic normal, put the mean and  variance in.  Simple transformations to standard form will end up changing k.